# Let arara continue upon failure

Tags: arara, compilation-error

I have a document which throws some errors, but I am satisfied with the end result. To avoid stopping at these harmless errors, I execute the following commands:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode texFile
bibtex texFile
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode texFile
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode texFile
```

I want to automate it using *arara*. My tex file contains the following markup:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode}
```

I run *arara* as `arara -v texFile` to see the detailed output. The first directive runs, however it stops executing the other three commands due to the error during the compilation. The manual for arara 4.0 states that

"As previously mentioned in Section 2.1, on page 8, if a task fails, arara will halt the entire execution at once and immediately report back to the user."

Can this somehow be circumvented so that the subsequent directives are also executed?

Comment: Errors are not harmless. Correct them.

Comment: True. Let me put it in another way. The existence of that error does not cause visible glitches, but correcting that would take quite a lot of time as it is a style file, whose author is unknown, and the file is poorly documented.

Comment: Sorry I have to much of experience with documents breaking completly just before some deadline because someone thought it wouldn't harm to ignore a few errors so I will in no case help you in such a task. Better spent your time on correcting the error than on searching for means to ignore it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have a file that throws an error at the first run, then compiles properly at the second run. I would be pleased if you look at [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514424/2288).