# Compilation error is removed by compiling again

Tags: errors, etoolbox, arara, fmtcount

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456315/2288), the first run of compilation results in the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. This exam contains \textbf{\NAMEquestions}

which has to be eliminated by running it for the second time. So, how can I get rid of the error at the first run in order to be able to use `arara`?

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape','-interaction=nonstopmode' ]}
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape','-interaction=nonstopmode' ]}
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\NAMEquestions\numquestions
\patchcmd{\NAMEquestions}{\exam@numquestions}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions} question\ifnum\exam@numquestions>1 s\fi}{}{}
\let\NAMEpages\numpages
\patchcmd{\NAMEpages}{\exam@lastpage}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@lastpage} page\ifnum\exam@lastpage>1 s\fi}{}{}
\let\NAMEpoints\numpoints
\patchcmd{\NAMEpoints}{\exam@numpoints}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numpoints} mark\ifnum\exam@numpoints>1 s\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This exam contains \textbf{\NAMEquestions} in \textbf{\NAMEpages} (including the cover) for a total of \textbf{\NAMEpoints}.

\begin{questions}
  \question[10] single question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because the definition of the macro is written into the aux file in the first run, and only available in the second run. Is your question also how to get rid of the error?

Comment: `Is your question also how to get rid of the error?` Yes, I have asked for a solution to be able to use arara :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exam` class takes precautions to check that the commands are defined, your code doesn't, because the braces are in the wrong position.

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\diaa@plural}[1]{\ifnum#1>1 s\fi}
\let\NAMEquestions\numquestions
\patchcmd{\NAMEquestions}
  {\exam@numquestions}
  {{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions\ question\diaa@plural\exam@numquestions}}
  {}{}
\let\NAMEpages\numpages
\patchcmd{\NAMEpages}
  {\exam@lastpage}
  {{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@lastpage\ page\diaa@plural\exam@lastpage}}
  {}{}
\let\NAMEpoints\numpoints
\patchcmd{\NAMEpoints}
  {\exam@numpoints}
  {{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numpoints\ mark\diaa@plural\exam@numpoints}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This exam contains \textbf{\NAMEquestions} in \textbf{\NAMEpages} (including the cover) for a total of \textbf{\NAMEpoints}.

\begin{questions}
  \question[10] single question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\numquestions` is

```latex
% exam.cls, line 1604:
\def\numquestions{\@ifundefined{exam@numquestions}%
  {\mbox{\normalfont\bfseries ??}}%
  \exam@numquestions
}% numquestions
```

and the token `\exam@newquestions` is the third argument to `\@ifundefined`. With your patch, only `\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions` is taken as the third argument and from `question` on the code is executed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know anything about arara (since I am *not* a duck) but this avoids errors.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\ifcsname exam@numquestions\endcsname%
\let\NAMEquestions\numquestions
\patchcmd{\NAMEquestions}{\exam@numquestions}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions} question\ifnum\exam@numquestions>1 s\fi}{}{}
\fi
\ifcsname exam@lastpage\endcsname%
\let\NAMEpages\numpages
\patchcmd{\NAMEpages}{\exam@lastpage}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@lastpage} page\ifnum\exam@lastpage>1 s\fi}{}{}
\let\NAMEpoints\numpoints
\fi
\ifcsname exam@numpoints\endcsname%
\patchcmd{\NAMEpoints}{\exam@numpoints}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numpoints} mark\ifnum\exam@numpoints>1 s\fi}{}{}
\fi%
\def\safetouse#1{%
\ifcsname#1\endcsname%
\csname#1\endcsname%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This exam contains \textbf{\safetouse{NAMEquestions}} in
\textbf{\safetouse{NAMEpages}} (including the cover) for a total of
\textbf{\safetouse{NAMEpoints}}.

\begin{questions}
  \question[10] single question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: May I ask an off-topic question about TikZ shape anchors?

Comment: @Diaa Yes, you may.

Comment: Thanks. In [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514350/2288), is it possible for the cylinder to use something like `anchor= ( $(c.before top)!0.5!(c.after top)$ )` inside the draw command without having to draw the cylinder first, then refer to it when drawing the horizontal line?

Comment: @Diaa I do not think so because before drawing the cylinder there is no (documented and probably no undocumented) anchor at that place. However, what prevents you from using `anchor=top` and adding the missing stretch either explicitly or via `append after command`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it that way. If you don't mind you can leave a comment on my question about how do it in a robust way without having to stretch the line by guessing.